# discord py - send message if user received a new rank (on_member_update)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to send users a private message if they earned a specific rank (like at level-up) but I don't know how I can do that.

What i tried:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before,after):
    try:
        role_id = 721847130238746636
        member = bot.get_guild(before.guild.id).get_member(before.id)
        if before.bot or after.bot:
            return
        else:
            if role_id not in bool(before.member.roles):
                if role_id in bool(after.member.roles):
                    print(f"{member.name} test dm message send")
                    await member.send('test dm message')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, I changed up your code a bit. `role_id` cannot be in a `bool` and without the bool it will not trigger anyways because `role_id` is an `id` and `before.roles` and `after.roles` will return a list which compares against the role name. So I used `get()` to get the role from the guild and check if that `role` is in `before.roles` & `after.roles`

```
@bot.event
    async def on_member_update(before, after):
        try:
            role = get(bot.get_guild(before.guild.id).roles, id=721847130238746636)
            member = bot.get_guild(before.guild.id).get_member(before.id)
            if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
                print(f"{member.name} test dm message send")
                await member.send('test dm message')
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e)
```

Code worked after I made the changes, if you haven't already also make sure you have intents enabled.